# Updating status strip label async/await

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, async-await, task

I have a WinForm, with a toolStripStatusLabel. There is a button, which spawns a new thread to perform its task. The status label needs to update during, and after this task is completed. The GUI elements are in the main thread. If I want to achieve this, can I place the relevant lines to update the label where the comments are below in the code snippet below? Also, I need to have another form open when this label is clicked. From my understanding of asynchronous coding, this should be straightforward, involving an event handler for the label, and the fact that control will return to the caller of the async method. Is this correct? I am relatively new to multithreaded and asynchronous programming, so I am quite confused.

```
// this is running in the main GUI thread
private async void Export_execute_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => do_export(filename, classes, System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(timestamp)));
        // if this is successful, status label should be update (task successful)
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        // status label should be updated (task failed)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, could you provide a brief example of that? I am still confused.

Comment: Sorry i missread this post on my coffee break, you can put your ui work where your comment is, this will run on the UI thread

Comment: Why don't you just try and see if it works?

Comment: Ok, yes, the event handler for that label seems to work as expected. I'm still working on updating it as required, putting the code where the comments are.

Comment: also you might want to protect against multiple hits while its exporting

Comment: Yes, in the actual code the button is disabled once clicked, and once it's finish processing, it's re-enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If there is something literally awaitable in the Export method then I think to make it an `async` method would be better.

```
private async void Export_execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await ExportAsync("file1", "classA", DateTime.Now);
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = $"Export finished at {DateTime.Now}";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = $"Export failed, {ex.ToString()}";
    }
}

private async Task ExportAsync(string fileName, string classes, DateTime timestamp)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel.Text = $"Export start at {timestamp}";
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    toolStripStatusLabel.Text = $"Have first half done {timestamp}";
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}

private void toolStripStatusLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to report progress is to use the [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) interface. There is already an implementation of this interface that you can use ([`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1)), and is generic so that you can supply any type of argument you want. In the example bellow the argument is a `string`. The key point is that the event [`Progress.ProgressChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1.progresschanged) is running in the UI thread, so you don't have to worry about it.

```
// This will run in the UI thread
private async void Export_Execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        var progress = new Progress<string>();
        progress.ProgressChanged += ExportProgress_ProgressChanged;
        // Task.Factory.StartNew allows to set advanced options
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Do_Export(filename, classes,
            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(timestamp), progress),
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
            TaskScheduler.Default);
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = $"Export completed successfully";
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel.Text = $"Export failed: {e.Message}";
    }
}

// This will run in the UI thread
private void ExportProgress_ProgressChanged(object sender, string e)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel.Text = e;
}

// This will run in a dedicated background thread
private void Do_Export(string filename, string classes, DateTime timestamp,
    IProgress<string> progress)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 10)
    {
        progress?.Report($"Export {i}% percent done");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a `BackgroundWorker` instead of your current `Task`? I prefer these because they allow easy communication between the main thread and the worker.

Note that `Export_execute_Click` is no longer marked as `async` in this scenario.

Example:

```cs
private void Export_execute_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs args) {

    // Method level objects are accessible throughout this process
    bool error = false;

    // Process
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker {
        WorkerReportsProgress = true
    };

    // This executes on main thread when a progress is reported
    worker.ProgressChanged += (e, ea) => {
        if (ea.UserState != null) {
            // ea.UserState.ToString() contains the string progress message
        }
    };

    // This executes as an async method on a background thread
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) => {
        try {
            var response = do_export(filename, classes, System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(timestamp)));
            if (response == whatever) {
                worker.ReportProgress(0, "Response from do_export() was `whatever`");
            } else {
                worker.ReportProgress(0, "Response from do_export() was something bad");
                error = true;
            }

        } catch (System.Exception e) {
            worker.ReportProgress(0, $"do_export() failed: {e}");
        }
    };

    // This executes on the main thread once the background worker has finished
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += async (o, ea) => {
        // You can communicate with your UI normally again here
        if (error) {
            // You had an error -- the exception in DoWork() fired
        } else {
            // You're all set
        }

        // If you have a busy-indicator, here is the place to disable it
        // ...
    };

    // I like to set a busy-indicator here, some sort of ajax-spinner type overlay in the main UI, indicating that the process is happening
    // ...

    // This executes the background worker, as outlined above
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Comment: The [`BackgroundWorker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker) class is considered old school these days. There is nothing wrong about it, other than its verbosity.